# Vectorized manipulation of an array, based on a function of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have an array that represents a function between 3D points. Therefore as index it gets 6-tuples. Now I want to apply a function on the elements of this array but this function depends not only on the value of an element but on its index as well. So if `A` is the matrix, and m and n are our 3D points that A[m,n] stores its value and k is a value between 0 and 3 then `f(A,k)[m,n]` is equal to:

-`m[k]**2` if `m==n`

-`m[k]**2-n[k]**2` otherwise

The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def func(a,k):
    b=np.empty(a.shape)
    for i in range(a.flatten().size):
        ind=np.unravel_index(i,a.shape)
        if ind[0:3]==ind[3:6]:
            b[ind]=a[ind]*ind[0:3][k]**2
        else:
            b[ind]=a[ind]*(ind[0:3][k]**2-ind[3:6][k]**2)
    return b
a=np.arange(729).reshape((3,3,3,3,3,3))
print func(a,2)
```

Is there anyway of vecotrizing this code?

P.S. This is a simplified version of what I actually need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `numpy.indices()` create the index array, then you can vecotrizing the calculation:

```
import numpy as np
def func(a,k):
    b=np.empty(a.shape)
    for i in range(a.flatten().size):
        ind=np.unravel_index(i,a.shape)
        if ind[0:3]==ind[3:6]:
            b[ind]=a[ind]*ind[0:3][k]**2
        else:
            b[ind]=a[ind]*(ind[0:3][k]**2-ind[3:6][k]**2)
    return b

def func2(a,k):
    b = np.empty(a.shape)
    ind = np.indices(a.shape).reshape(6, -1)
    mask = np.all(ind[:3] == ind[3:6], axis=0)
    ar = a.ravel()
    br = b.ravel()
    br[mask] = ar[mask]*ind[k, mask]**2
    mask = ~mask
    br[mask] = ar[mask]*(ind[k, mask]**2 - ind[3+k, mask]**2)
    return b

a = np.arange(729).reshape((3,3,3,3,3,3))
b1 = func(a, 2)
b2 = func2(a, 2)
np.allclose(b1, b2)
```

here is the %timeit result:

```
%timeit func(a, 2)
%timeit func2(a, 2)
```

output:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 579 µs per loop
```

You can optimize it a little for your case:

```
def func3(a,k):
    b = np.empty(a.shape)
    ind = np.indices(a.shape).reshape(6, -1)
    mask = ~np.all(ind[:3] == ind[3:6], axis=0)
    ar = a.ravel()
    br = b.ravel()
    br[:] = ar*ind[k]**2
    br[mask] -= ar[mask]*ind[3+k, mask]**2
    return b
```